# Can't open shared library 'libmemcached.so'

Tags: mysql

I download the source code :Generic Linux (Architecture Independent), Compressed TAR Archive

I'm using ubuntu 12.02

and I followed :

1) Install libevent.

2) Build and install MySQL:

```
shell> groupadd mysql 
shell> useradd -r -g mysql mysql 
shell> tar zxvf mysql-VERSION.tar.gz 
shell> cd mysql-VERSION 
shell> cmake . -DWITH_INNODB_MEMCACHED=ON 
shell> make 
shell> make install
```

3) Copy mysql-5.6.11/plugin/innodb_memcached/innodb_memcache/innodb_engine.so and mysql-5.6.11/plugin/innodb_memcached/daemon_memcached/libmemcached.so into /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/

4) Start mysql and execute the configuration script:

```
mysql> /usr/local/mysql/share/innodb_memcached_config.sql
```

5) Install the daemon_memcached plugin:

```
mysql> install plugin daemon_memcached soname "libmemcached.so";
```

I got the error at the last step.

ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'libmemcached.so' (errno: 0 API version for DAEMON plugin is too different)

Comment: The error seems to indicate the problem. Did you compare any involved version numbers?

Comment: Not sure what are involved version numbers. The download version is mysql-5.6.11. I have also download libmem the latest version. What else should I check?

Comment: Obviously mysql doesnt want the version of your memcached plugin. So you will have to find out what memcached version is compatible to mysql 5.6.11 and use that one.

Comment: I have only download the Generic Linux (Architecture Independent) source code online, I thought this already contains the plugin, isnt it? I didnt download extra plugin? So what plugin version is this?